# Why does my rectangle move faster in one direction than in the opposite?

Tags: java, slick

I am using Slick2d to create a top-down game, however an rectangle than I am drawing to the display is moving faster to the left than to the right, and faster up than down.

I am updating frames like so:

```
public void update(GameContainer gameContainer, int delta) throws SlickException { 
    player = new Rectangle(playerX, playerY, 10, 20);

    if (gameContainer.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_LEFT)) {
        x -= delta * 0.1f;
    }
    if (gameContainer.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_RIGHT)) {
        x += delta * 0.1f;
    }
    if (gameContainer.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_UP)) {
        y -= delta * 0.1f;
    }
    if (gameContainer.getInput().isKeyDown(Input.KEY_DOWN)) {
        y += delta * 0.1f;
    }
}
```

I then simply draw the rectangle to the display. It is noteworthy that the rectangle class is a`org.newdawn.slick.geom.Rectangle`.

Why are the speeds for the movement different, and how can I fix this?

***EDIT:*** I have fixed the problem by slowing the movement to the left and up, but this does not explain why the problem occurs

Comment: The code seems to be fine. You can put debug statements inside each if block to check just in case any value is not getting set properly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is most likely a rounding error. I'm guessing that x and y are ints.

Keeping track of the x and y values as floats, I expect will fix the issue.

Consider if the values are being floored:

Moving Left `10 - 1.6 = 8`

Moving Right `10 + 1.6 = 11`

Comment: Don't ints round towards 0? I ran this code `System.out.println((int) -1.7);` on my machine and it printed -1. But still, he shouldn't be storing coordinates as ints.

Comment: Yes, they will but screen coords are never negative.. so bad example on my part. Try `5-1.6 = 3`, not 4

Comment: Oh, good point.

Comment: Keep in mind, they do not "round toward 0," they truncate. This distinction is important. For instance, 1.9999 truncates to 1 and 2.0001 truncates to 2. That's where this unexpected behavior is most likely occurring, in the truncation.